# I cannot get into the next element with jquery after click

Tags: jquery

I have a code, and I'm trying to get into the next element, but I cannot. Some ideas?

HTML

```
<label class="right">
  <input>
</label>

<label>
  <input>
</label>
```

CSS

```
 .right {
  float: right;
}
```

jQuery

```
var next = $(".right").next();
var btn = $("button");

btn.on("click", function(){
    next.addClass("right");
})
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vg5ngoyq/1/

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work as it doesn't have jQuery specified. Is this the case in your existing code?

Comment: Are your `<input>`s `type="text"` or `type="button"`? If they are `type="button"`, then `var btn = $('input[type="button"]')`

Comment: @simon yeap, this is my existing code, in my Atom text editor, and I specified there jQuery, and it's not working there

Comment: @zer00ne <input> is a checkbox

Comment: If you have jQuery defined in your environment, you need to ensure that your paths are actually correct and it is being loaded properly and that your jQuery code isn't called until after it is loaded (try putting it in a `$(function(){ ... });` block. If all else fails, check your Console to see if any other errors are present.

Comment: @RionWilliams I will try your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your example didn't appear to have jQuery defined prior to actually calling your jQuery-based code. After adding it in, it should work as expected :

```
<!-- Make sure you have something like this defined before ever calling jQuery code-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
         // It is now safe to use your jQuery code here...
    });
</script>
```

**Example**

[image]

```js
var next = $(".right").next();
var btn = $("button");

btn.on("click", function() {
  next.addClass("right");
})
```

```css
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="right">
  <input>
</label>

<label>
  <input>
</label>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Way to make a complex answer for complex questions (thumbsup)

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't know that I have to add jquery to the jsfiddle, but I always add it to my project, and it's not working in there...

Comment: If you have jQuery defined in your environment, you need to ensure that your paths are actually correct and it is being loaded properly and that your jQuery code isn't called until after it is loaded (try putting it in a `$(function(){ ... });` block. If all else fails, check your Console to see if any other errors are present (look for any 404s, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You simply missed including jquery in your fiddle.

Outside of jsFiddle, include jquery like so, for example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

[have a look](https://jsfiddle.net/vg5ngoyq/3/)

Comment: thanks :) I have a jquery in my code, and it's still not working

Comment: Have a look at the fiddle I posted as well as at rion williams quite complete answer to your question. It's positive that you missed to include jquery before using it.